# JSON Redirect from MVC Controller not working

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, routes

I've tried the steps outlined in other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864972/how-to-redirect-to-a-controller-action-from-a-jsonresult-method-in-asp-net-mvc)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175942/json-redirecttoaction) and it just doesn't work. I end up getting redirected to a white screen that just says ... `{"redirectTo":"/Administrator/Home"}`

## C`#`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ControllerMethodHere(ViewModel model) {
        // my controller code goes here.
        return Json(new {
            redirectTo = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

## Javascript

```
    this.save = function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: $('form').attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(this),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
                }
            });
    };
```

Comment: If that's what you are seeing, it doesn't seem to me like you're making an XHR request. Have you looked at Firebug/Fiddler to see if you're actually making an XHR request?

Comment: I don't quite know how to do that, but everything else is working just fine... I mean, it does return the data, it just doesn't read it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this:

```
window.location = data.redirectTo;
```

Comment: Yes, this was it. I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: The simple solutions are always the most difficult to track down. Glad it worked out for you!